# How to hide stack trace from service worker fetch?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

I have service worker like this:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       // ...
       fetch(event.request).then(resolve).catch(reject);
    }));
});
```

I don't remember where I found this code, but when I use ad blocker together with 404, in console I see stack trace:

[image: Service worker Stack Trace in Dev console]

Is there a way to get rid of that stack trace. I only need to know that the fetch failed (see the second error message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that the proper way is to swallow the error, the network seems to get proper error that appear in Network and console tabs in Dev Tools.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    var req = fetch(event.request).then(resolve).catch(() => {});
    event.respondWith(req);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is coming from the stack property of the `Error` object (or derived class) that is passed to the `reject` method. One solution is  to reject with a string:

```
catch( err=>reject(err.message))
```

If, however, you want more information about the url that failed to fetch you would need to include it from information in `event.request`. How to include it depends on whether `event.request` is a url string, `URL` or `Request` object or object with a stringifier. Without exact information you could try something like

```
catch( err=>reject("Fetch failed to fetch " + (request?.url || request )));
```

Comment: It seems that you solution also show uncatched exception. Only the stack trace is missing. I don't want to see the error at all. Any soution?

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the `stack` property:

```js
const e = new Error('Uh oh');
console.log(e.name, e.message, e.stack);

e.stack = '';
console.log(e.name, e.message, e.stack);
```

Comment: After removing the stack there is still duplicated `sw.js:61  Uncaught (in promise) `, but without the stack, I don't want that extra error in console. The proper solution is @traktor answer.